# Dealing with Delegates in Separate UIViewController(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uialertview

I am currently working on a Sprite Kit game, and I am having some issues with setting/using delegates. I know how delegates work and all that, but I am trying to have the user have the ability to play my game, and once they hit the pause button, have the game pause. Then, I have a UIAlertView appear asking for 'resume game' or 'sign up' for a newsletter type thing. I have a website that I have a new UIViewController appear under, and while the view controller is open, I want the game to be paused, which it is. My issue is when I am done with the website, i want the game to resume at that point. My issue:

- after user hits "close" button on the website, have the UIViewController dismiss, and then have the SKScene.paused = no.

Here is the code for how i go about doing that.

```
// in the view controller class
- (IBAction)closeWebsite {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.delegate closeWebsiteAndResumeGame];
}
```

here is the code for the class that is my main UIViewController, where it pauses the game.

```
// in the main view controller
@interface ADViewController () <ADWebViewViewControllerDelegate>

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *title = [ alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if ([title isEqualToString:@"Resume Game"]) {
    _gamePlay.scene.paused = NO;
}
else {
    // here i load the other viewController
    ADWebViewViewController *webView;
    webView.delegate = self;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        webView = [[ADWebViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ADWebViewViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
    else {
        webView = [[ADWebViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ADWebViewViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self presentViewController:webView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
//_gamePlay.scene.paused = NO;
}

- (void) closeWebsiteAndResumeGame {
   _gamePlay.scene.paused = NO;
}
```

I appreciate all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I didn't need to use a delegate. All i had to do was link some items within Interface Builder, and it worked perfectly :)